# How to include custom value in amcharts series for calculation

Tags: amcharts

How do we include the new custom variable to define the bullet location based on avgTime in chart.data

We are unable to assign the avgTime to openBullet.locationX = avgTime; like this.

If i add the avgTime to locationX it is throwing the error like avgTime is not defined.

Find the below code for your reference

```
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

chart.data = [{
  "name": "John",
  "startTime": 8,
  "endTime": 11,
  "avgTime": 0.5,
  "color": chart.colors.next()
}, {
  "name": "Joe",
  "startTime": 10,
  "endTime": 13,
  "avgTime": 0.8,
  "color": chart.colors.next()
}, {
  "name": "Susan",
  "startTime": 11,
  "endTime": 18,
  "avgTime": 0.1,
  "color": chart.colors.next()
}, {
  "name": "Eaton",
  "startTime": 15,
  "endTime": 19,
  "avgTime": 0,
  "color": chart.colors.next()
}];

var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "name";
categoryAxis.renderer.inversed = true;
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;

var valueAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
//valueAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 50;

var columnSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
columnSeries.dataFields.categoryY = "name";
columnSeries.dataFields.valueX = "endTime";
columnSeries.dataFields.openValueX = "startTime";
columnSeries.columns.template.tooltipText = "[bold]{categoryY}[/]\nstarts at {openValueX}\nends at {valueX}";

var columnTemplate = columnSeries.columns.template;
columnTemplate.strokeOpacity = 0;
columnTemplate.propertyFields.fill = "color";
//columnTemplate.height = am4core.percent(100);

//var openBullet = columnSeries.bullets.create(am4charts.CircleBullet);
//openBullet.locationX = avgTime;

var circleBullet = columnSeries.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
circleBullet.circle.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
circleBullet.circle.strokeWidth = 2;
circleBullet.locationX = /**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 * 
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 * 
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

chart.data = [{
  "name": "John",
  "startTime": 8,
  "endTime": 11,
  "avgTime": 0.5,
  "color": chart.colors.next()
}, {
  "name": "Joe",
  "startTime": 10,
  "endTime": 13,
  "avgTime": 0.8,
  "color": chart.colors.next()
}, {
  "name": "Susan",
  "startTime": 11,
  "endTime": 18,
  "avgTime": 0.1,
  "color": chart.colors.next()
}, {
  "name": "Eaton",
  "startTime": 15,
  "endTime": 19,
  "avgTime": 0,
  "color": chart.colors.next()
}];

var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "name";
categoryAxis.renderer.inversed = true;
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;

var valueAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
//valueAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 50;

var columnSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
columnSeries.dataFields.categoryY = "name";
columnSeries.dataFields.valueX = "endTime";
columnSeries.dataFields.openValueX = "startTime";
columnSeries.columns.template.tooltipText = "[bold]{categoryY}[/]\nstarts at {openValueX}\nends at {valueX}";

var columnTemplate = columnSeries.columns.template;
columnTemplate.strokeOpacity = 0;
columnTemplate.propertyFields.fill = "color";
//columnTemplate.height = am4core.percent(100);

//var openBullet = columnSeries.bullets.create(am4charts.CircleBullet);
//openBullet.locationX = avgTime;

var circleBullet = columnSeries.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
circleBullet.circle.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
circleBullet.circle.strokeWidth = 2;
circleBullet.locationX = {avgTime};


var labelBullet = columnSeries.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
labelBullet.label.text = "{avgTime}";
labelBullet.label.dx = +20;
labelBullet.locationX = 0.2;;


var labelBullet = columnSeries.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
labelBullet.label.text = "{avgTime}";
labelBullet.label.dx = +20;
labelBullet.locationX = 0.2;
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and show the _exact_ error message as searchable, copyable, formatted text.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure if I understood your question correctly. To set the position of the bullets you have to set the value in the `propertyFields` accounding to the name of the value in your data:

```
circleBullet.propertyFields.locationX = "avgTime";
```

I created a [code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pGxXzp) with your example code. Hope that helps.

**EDIT:** According to the response from *zeroin* you should consider to change your `avgTime` to `1 - avgTime`, because it is rendered beginning at the end of the column.

Comment: This is really good answer. The only thing which the user might need to do is to change avgTime to 1-avgTime, as the bullet location is calculated from the valueX and not from openValueX, so if you set avgTime to 0, the bullet will be at the end of the column and you might want the opposite.

Comment: Thank you @zeroin, i was already wondering about that. I edited my post to add that information.